# Regular Expression Url Address

Tags: javascript, regex

My URL String:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions

My regex : `[\w.]+`

Result: `["http","stackoverflow.com","questions"]`

How I ignore `.*` in `stackoverflow.com` only one regex.

Result I want: `["http","stackoverflow","questions"]`

Comment: Just use [`\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/bI1sK1/1).

Comment: ["http","stackoverflow","questions"] not ["http","stackoverflow","com","questions"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex that captures into Group 1 all alphanumeric/underscore chunks that are not preceded with `.`:

```
/(?:^|[^.])\b(\w+)\b/g
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cF7yH5/1).

Breakdown:

- `(?:^|[^.])` - matches (but does not store in a group buffer) the beginning of a string or any character but a literal dot
- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(\w+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more word characters
- `\b` - trailing word boundary

Sample code:

```js
var re = /(?:^|[^.])\b(\w+)\b/g; 
var str = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions';
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    res.push(m[1]);
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

**Another solution** based on the assumption the word character should not be followed with `/`:

```
\b\w+\b(?!\/)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cF7yH5/2)

```js
var re = /\b\w+\b(?!\/)/g; 
var str = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions';
var res = str.match(re);
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Note that both solutions require a word boundary to work properly, just a negated character class (#1) or a lookahead (#2) won't work by themselves (partial matches will be rejected thanks to `\b`).